# Show that $X_t = \int_0^t B_s^2 dB_s$ is a martingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

In this post [Is this Stochastic integral a martingale ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978014/is-this-stochastic-integral-a-martingale?rq=1) it is claimed that the process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ defined by $$X_t = \int_0^t B_s^2 dB_s$$ is a martingale.

I want to be able to show this directly, without any machinery higher than the Ito formula. I get to here: 
For $s < t$ consider that \begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E} (X_t - X_s \vert \mathscr{F}_s) &=& \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t B_r^2 dB_r - \int_0^s B_r^2 dB_r \Bigg \vert \mathscr{F}_s \right) \\
&=& \mathbb{E} \left( \int_s^t B_r^2 dB_r \Bigg \vert \mathscr{F}_s \right) 
\end{eqnarray*}

before getting stuck. Any assistance is appreciated.

Is it possible to show that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale directly by computing the conditional expectation?

Comment: What do you mean machinery higher than the Ito Formula?   If $M_t$ is a martingale then integrating with respect to $M_t$ is also a martingale.  The Ito Integral preserves the local martingale property.  So you know $B_t$ is a martingale so ...

Comment: Did's answer to the previous question had some wise words about Ito not really being much of an approach here. (And it's unclear what you mean by "machinery higher than Ito" anyway). You have $dX_t = B_t^2 dB_t$... that's clearly a Martingale by seat-of-your-pants reasons, which is maybe what you mean... In which case, what else do you need?

Comment: @JoaquinSan  Is it possible to show that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale by directly computing the conditional expectation?

Comment: @YinPeiTo Yes, use the definition of the integral and the tower law.

Comment: Recall how you prove that the ito integral preserves the local martingale property.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493640/preservation-of-martingale-property

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using Ito: By Ito's formula, applied to $f(x)={1\over 3} x^3$, you have
$$
\int_0^t B_s^2\,dB_s = {1\over 3} B_t^3-\int_0^t B_s\,ds.
$$
It's not hard to take conditional expectations of the objects on the right side of this equality.

Comment: I'm curious how you take the conditional expectation on the right hand side easily since $B_t^3$ is not a martingale?

Comment: To condition on $\mathcal F_s$ for $0\le s<t$, write $B_t=B_s+(B_t-B_s)$, so that
$$
B_t^3=B_s^3+3B_s^2(B_t-B_s)+3B_s(B_t-B_s)^2+(B_t-B_s)^3,
$$
and use the fact that $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ and is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $t-s$.